# Conditions for polynomial $f$ such that $f(n) \in \mathbb{N}$ for enough $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$ implies $f$ has rational coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, polynomials

This question is suggested by this one:
[prove: coefficients of $f(x)$ are rational numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516555/prove-coefficients-of-fx-are-rational-numbers)

What are the weakest sufficient conditions and
strongest necessary conditions
on a set of positive integers
$S$
such that
if $f$ is a polynomial
with complex coefficients
and $f(n)$ is an integer for
all $n \in S$,
then
all the coefficients of $f$
are
rational numbers?

That question shows that
a sufficient condition
is that $S$ contains
all positive integers.

I conjecture that
a necessary condition is that,
for every prime $p$,
$p \in S$.

There may be a similar sufficient
condition something like
"for all prime powers
$p^k$ there is a $n \in S$
such that
$p^k | n$."

Can there be such an $S$
with density zero?
If not,
how small can
$\frac{\#\{k|(k \le n) \land (k \in S)\}}{n} $
be?

How about
$\sum_{n \in S} \frac1{n}$ diverges?

An intuitive form of this might be:

How "thin" can $S$ be
and still force
$f(n) \in \mathbb{N}$
for all $n \in S$
implies that 
the coefficients of $f$
are rational.

How "thick" can $S$ be
while a polynomial
$f$
with at least one non-rational coefficient
exists
such that
$f(n) \in \mathbb{N}$
for all $n \in S$.

Comment: Wouldn't any infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ satisfy this property ?

Comment: And, conversely, no finite set will do, since you can take a polynomial that vanishes on a finite set and multiply it by an arbitrary complex number.

Comment: I'll think about these comments tomorrow. There might be less to this than meets the eye.

Comment: For a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$,
$$\begin{align}
& \text{all coefficients of } f(x) \text{ are rational}\\
\implies & f(x) \text{ are rational for all rational } x\\
\implies & f(x) \text{ are rational for infinitely many rational }x \\
\implies & f(x) \text{ are rational for } n + 1 \text{ integral x}\\
\implies & \text{all coefficients of } f(x) \text{ are rational}
\end{align}$$
In the last step, we have used Lagrange interpolation formula to express $f(x)$ in terms
of its values of any $n+1$ integers.